# How to get coordinates of a link in iframe in javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, coordinates

I want to get some link's coordinates in an iframe and show it as a heat map in another iframe.

I'm doing this with getBoundingClientRect() like below:

```
element = $('#myFrame').contents().find('a[href$="'+myLink+'"]');
var theElement = element[0];
if(element.length) {
  positionInfo = element[0].getBoundingClientRect(); 
  coordinates = {
    'x' :positionInfo.x, 
    'y' : positionInfo.y, 
    'width' : positionInfo.width
  };
}
```

But coordinates are not correct.I think it's because i used it in a iframe (either in getting and showing)

How can i fix it?

Comment: You should share more code and make a working snippet of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to add the coordinates of the iframe itself:

```
$('#myFrame').get(0).getBoundingClientRect()
```